# PEAR Package for Symfony Plugin on Windows

Tags: windows, plugins, symfony1, package, pear

I have been looking for a way to create a PEAR package out of my Symfony plugin on Windows. I am unable to find any utility or tutorial explaining the process.
In case there is no solution, I will have to manually prepare my package.xml, which is kind of sad in this world of automation.
Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use the [PEAR_PackageFileManager2](http://pear.php.net/package/PEAR_PackageFileManager2) for that task. It works on windows too. All you need to do is some finetunig afterwards.

Comment: thanks, but when I see the dependencies on other PEAR packages, I get a headache. Do I need to install all of them. Because right now Im not relying on PEAR. Im working in Netbeans right now. Does that utility simple work on the command line? and what is the command to get started? thanks

Comment: Hi. This works great for me. But what is the API method to add a Symfony dependency. I found methods for php & pearInstaller dependencies. Can you throw some light please?

Comment: Got hold of the API Doc after some googling:

URL: http://pear.php.net/reference/PEAR-1.7.2/PEAR/PEAR_PackageFile_v2_rw.html

Signature:
void addPackageDepWithChannel( optional|required $type, string $name, string $channel, [string $min = false], [string $max = false], [string $recommended = false], [string $exclude = false], [bool $providesextension = false], [array|false $nodefault = false])

Usage:
$p2->addPackageDepWithChannel('required', 'PEAR_PackageFileManager2', 'pear.php.net', '0.1.0', false, '0.1.0');

Thanks

Comment: have a new problem, see if you can help Sir: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770228/symfony-plugin-upload-error-you-must-specify-the-min-version-for-symfony